# 210v DC CV/CC supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, linear-regulator

I have an old variable power supply that consists of a multi tapped transformer, a bridge rectifier and a choke. The transformer has two sets of taps on it, 6 coarse and 6 fine, giving 36 voltage outputs between 10v ~210v DC, maximum current is 8amps. Being such a simple design the output voltage obviously varies depending on the current being drawn. I'm looking for a way to add a regulator stage to the output so that the output voltage will remain constant and ideally so that I can have an adjustable current limit. Power supply is used for lab work and battery charging.

I'd consider linear or SMPS designs, simpler is better as my electronics skills are pretty low level.

I've had a look at some SMPS ICs and linear regulators, but I'm struggling to find one that can cope with the input voltage and current I require. Can I just series up a number of isolated regulators to get the Vmax rating I require?

If I use a SMPS design, would I just use the highest tap positions on the transformer, or is there still an advantage to using the taps to get closer to the desired output voltage?

Any suggestions on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _"electronics skills are pretty low level"_ This pretty much rules out SMPS if you need to develop it yourself. But if you don't care about efficiency and have room for a hefty heatsink, it should be a good linear power supply exercise for you. _"Can I just series up a number of isolated regulators to get the Vmax rating I require?"_ Depends alot on how you do it. Please draw a block diagram or schematic.

Comment: "Can I just series up a number of isolated regulators" - ideally you should use one regulator to stabilise the DC output. You may wish to use a floating regulator on top of a bunch of zener diodes, such that the regulator only sees the "top" few volts of the supply. For example, you could have 200 V worth of zeners and the final 10 V could be left to the regulator to stabilise. Alternatively you could consider a [Maida-style regulator](https://attackllama.com/hardware/high-voltage-filter/) that uses a LM317 in combination with a MOSFET that ensures the LM317 always floats near to the HV input.

Comment: @Sean Thanks for your comments the Maida-style regulator looks very interesting.